# Parse key-value pairs with pyparsing where values may continue over multiple lines

Tags: python, pyparsing

How can I parse key-property definitions such as the following with `pyparsing`?

```
some_key a b c d
other_key /some/path /some/other/path.pl \
  '$SOME_ENV_VAR$' \
  '$OTHER_ENV_VAR$'
```

Keys in this example are `some_key` and `other_key`. Values are the rests of the lines including `[ \t]` after whitespace that is following the key names, with an option for line continuation with `\`.

I am relatively new to `pyparsing` and this exceeds my current capabilities.

Comment: What tells you that `some_key` and `other_key` are keys? Because they start in column 1?

Comment: @PaulMcG That's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/greghaskins/pyparsing) for `pyparsing` (e.g. for [`cppStyleComment`](https://github.com/greghaskins/pyparsing/blob/master/src/pyparsing.py#L3696-L3696)) was instructive and the following now works for me:

```
name = pp.Word(pp.alphas + '_', pp.alphanums + '_')
value = pp.Regex(r'(?:[^\n]*\\\n)*[^\n]*')
definition = name + value
```